# Logical Pattern - Produce the expected outputs

Tags: logic

I failed recently on trying to work out a logical pattern on a online coding game.

This particular game title is called Reverse. You get a list of inputs and you have to guess correctly the result set.

So, here are some inputs and result sets.

Test 1

> Input- 4,0,1,2,3
>
> Output - True, False, True, False

Test 2

> Input - 1, 44
>
> Output - true

Test 3

> Input - 1, 179
>
> Output - false

Test 4

> Input - 3, 3254, 24, 654
>
> Output - true, true, true

Can anyone see the pattern?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a logic puzzle, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a pattern. If we exclude the first value of each input set, the ouput is simply telling if the number is even or odd. I don't feel like it's the right answer, but that's all I have discovered.

Comment: As correct as any other answer I guess. You could also say that the output indicates whether the concatenation of each sequential pair is even: "4,0,1,2,3" => "40, 01, 12, 13" => true, false, true, false. Amounts to the same thing.

Comment: I think you got it there Odonno, and thanks Blorgbeard I think you added to it correctly too with the first parameter being redundant and probably just there to throw you off.